# how to hide Multi-select picklist field value based on profile

Tags: community

i want to hide certain values to hide in  Multi-select pick list based on profile. i have tried validation rule for hide but it saying **Error: Field__c is a multi-select pick list field. Multi-select pick list fields are only supported in certain functions**.

Comment: Validation rules don't "hide" values, they can only produce error messages. As such, you might be experiencing an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Consider making an **[edit]** to describe what you're trying to do, the source problem, rather than a specific solution you've already gotten stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to hide / show options within a multi picklist based on Profiles.

I believe you will need to use **RecordTypes** and assign the respective **Picklist** values to the appropriate Record Type. The Record Types are then assigned to Profiles.

Refer the following article, to understand how to [Assign Record Types to Profiles in the Original Profile User Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_recordtype.htm&type=5).

Comment: i am having record type but i want to hide based on profile